# Examples of overly wordy theorem.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm writing this paper on math style and I wanted to include an example of how old papers used to word things in a very verbose way without using any symbolic notation. I'm thinking of things like

> "Quantities, and the ratios of quantities, which in any finite time converge continually to equality, and before the end of that time approach nearer to the one to the other than by any given difference, become ultimately equal" (Newton's Principia)

to say that $x_n ,y_n \to L$ implies $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$.

I'm looking for more examples (and links to texts) of this form, wordy theorems that have very simple statements with proper notation.

Comment: You can find dozens of nineteenth century calculus texts available as pdfs for free. They're full of this stuff.

Comment: The quotation contains an error: the translation should read *nearer the one to the other than by any*. (I’ve also seen the translation *nearer to each other than by any*.)

Comment: Note that the meaning of the "translation" is quite different from what Newton was saying.

Comment: @André: If I’m not mistaken, what he’s saying is approximately that if $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$, then $\lim_nx_n=\lim_ny_n$, with an implicit assumption that the limits exist. (*Approximately* because our notation contains some implicit assumptions that he would not have made.)

Comment: I'd say that example is typical of 17th-century style, which is extremely verbose; one might even say "Baroque". The 19th century is by comparison more concise. Also, this excerpt from *Principia* has been translated from Latin, which is relatively wordy compared with English, just as French is.

Comment: He is primarily interested in "ratios of quantities." Apart from that, he is basically quoting Archimedes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How old are we talking? Many ancient Greek results were exceedingly verbose because they were algebraic in essence, but were forced to be couched in geometric terms.

For example:

> If a straight line is bisected, and a straight line is added to it in a straight line, then the square on the whole with the added straight line and the square on the added straight line both together are double the sum of the square on the half and the square described on the straight line made up of the half and the added straight line as on one straight line.

In other words: $(x + y)^2 + (x-y)^2 = 2(x^2 + y^2)$

Comment: This is a good suggestion. If OP wants examples of theorems that are wordy, until you put them into modern algebraic notation, she should look at mathematical treatises that predate the modern notation. [For example, the *Lilavati* of Bhāskara II](http://books.google.com/books?id=AoX5q7JjM2kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lilavati&sa=X&ei=WR81UuGoHZLl4AOM4ICABg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage) (1587) is full of “Split the given number into two parts. To the sum of the squares of the two parts add twice the product of the two parts.The result is the square.” Or, as we now say, $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a so-so example of verbosity and I would be the last to find fault with Chebyshev's French, which I think is quite elegant. It may seem slightly verbose to someone used to the parsimony of symbols.

From his celebrated proof of Bertrand's postulate, on the 13th page of his paper:

"So, whenever *a* surpasses 160, on can assign between *a* and $2a-2$ two new limits [$L_1$ and $L_2$], and as they necessarily contain a prime number, one will be certain to find a prime number which surpasses *a* and remains less than $2a-2,$ which proves the *postulatum* of M. Bertrand for all values of *a* which exceed 160. As for values of *a* which are not greater than 160, this *postulatum* is verified with the help of tables of prime numbers."

M$\acute{\text{e}}$moire sur les nombres premiers, p. 63.

Answer (score 1):

Not a theorem but a couple of titles of papers:

"Über Funktionen, welche in gewissen Punkten endliche Differential-quotienten jeder endlichen Ordnung, aber keine Taylorsche Reihenentwicklung besitzen" [A. Pringsheim, Math. Ann. 44 (1894) pp. 41-56]. Short version: On $C^\infty$ non-analytic functions.

"Einleitende Bemerkungen zur Fortsetzung meiner Mitteilung unter dem Titel 'Grundzüge eines neuen Systems der Grundlagen der Mathematik'" [S. Lesniewski, Collectanea Logica 1 (1938) pp. 1-60]

I think there were many more such titles in the good old days; these are two that I happen to remember because I encountered them myself (back in the 1960's).

Comment: The subtitle of Edgar Palmer's monograph *Graphical Evolution* is “An introduction to the theory of random graphs, wherein the most relevant probability models for graphs are described together with certain threshold functions which facilitate the careful study of the structure of a graph as it grows and specifically reveal the mysterious circumstances surrounding the abrupt appearance of the unique giant component which systematically absorbs its neighbors, devouring the larger first and ruthlessly continuing until the last isolated vertices have been swallowed up, whereupon the giant is…

Comment: …suddenly brought under control by a spanning cycle. The text is laced with challenging exercises especially designed to instruct, and its accompanied by an appendix stuffed with useful formulas that everyone should know.”